# Add sheet from api step by step and dynamically

Tags: android, api, gson, retrofit2, rx-java2

I am training to work with api and the problem arose that when scrolling the RecyclerView, I need the data to be added, namely, "page" is added, and thus the content is added.
I have achieved that before reaching the end of the list, the "onReachEndListener" method is triggered, but I cannot understand the implementation of adding to the sheet. PLEASE HELP ME!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SwitchMaterial switchMaterial;
    private TextView textViewPopularity, textViewTopRated;
    private RecyclerView recyclerViewPosters;
    private MovieAdapter movieAdapter;
    private MainViewModel viewModel;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;


    private static final int LOADER_ID = 122;
    private LoaderManager loaderManager;

    private static int page = 1;
    private static String methodOfSort;
    private static boolean isLoaning = true;

    private static String lang;


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.itemMain:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.itemFavourite:
                Intent i = new Intent(this, FavouriteActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private int getColumnCount() {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        int width = (int) (displayMetrics.widthPixels / displayMetrics.density);
        return width / 185 > 2 ? width / 2 : 2;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lang = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
        viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel.class);

        recyclerViewPosters = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewPosters);
        switchMaterial = findViewById(R.id.switchSort);
        textViewPopularity = findViewById(R.id.textViewPopularity);
        textViewTopRated = findViewById(R.id.textViewTopRated);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBarLoading);
        movieAdapter = new MovieAdapter();
        recyclerViewPosters.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, getColumnCount()));
        recyclerViewPosters.setAdapter(movieAdapter);
        switchMaterial.setChecked(true);
        myOnClick();

        LiveData<List<Movie>> moviesFromLiveData = viewModel.getMovies();
        moviesFromLiveData.observe(this, new Observer<List<Movie>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Movie> movies) {
                movieAdapter.setMovies(movies);
            }
        });

    }

    private void myOnClick() {
        switchMaterial.setOnCheckedChangeListener((compoundButton, b) -> {
            page = 1;
            setMethodOfSort(b);
        });
        switchMaterial.setChecked(false);

        textViewPopularity.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            setMethodOfSort(false);
            switchMaterial.setChecked(false);
        });
        textViewTopRated.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            setMethodOfSort(true);
            switchMaterial.setChecked(true);
        });

        movieAdapter.setOnPosterClickListener(position -> {
            Movie movie = movieAdapter.getMovies().get(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("id", movie.getId());
            startActivity(intent);
        });

        movieAdapter.setOnReachEndListener(() -> {
            if (!isLoaning){
                viewModel.deleteAllMovies();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewModel.loadDataImage(lang, methodOfSort, Integer.toString(page));
                Log.d("isLoaning", Integer.toString(page));

            }

        });
        recyclerViewPosters.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

                if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)) {

                    Log.d("isLoaning", Integer.toString(page));
                    LiveData<List<Movie>> moviesFromLiveData = viewModel.getMovies();
                    moviesFromLiveData.observe(MainActivity.this, new Observer<List<Movie>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Movie> movies) {

                            viewModel.insertMovie(movies);
                            movieAdapter.addMovies(movies);
                            page++;
                            isLoaning = false;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });


    }
    private void setMethodOfSort(boolean b){
        if(b) {
            methodOfSort = SORT_BY_TOP_RATED;
            Log.d("setMethodOfSort", methodOfSort);
            textViewPopularity.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            textViewTopRated.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.teal_200));
        }
        else {
            methodOfSort = SORT_BY_POPULARITY;
            Log.d("setMethodOfSort", methodOfSort);
            textViewPopularity.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.teal_200));
            textViewTopRated.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
        }
        viewModel.loadData(lang, methodOfSort ,Integer.toString(page));

    }
```

Model:

```
public class MainViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private static MovieDatabase database;
    private LiveData<List<Movie>> movies;
    private LiveData<List<FavouriteMovie>> favouriteMovies;
    private LiveData<String> methodOfSort;
    private CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable;
    private MutableLiveData<Throwable> errors;
    public static final String SMALL_POSTER_SIZE = "w185";
    private static final String KEY_POSTER_PATH = "poster_path";
    public static final String SORT_BY_POPULARITY = "popularity.desc";
    public static final String SORT_BY_TOP_RATED = "vote_average.desc";
    public static final int POPULARITY = 0;
    public static final int TOP_RATED = 1;

    public MainViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        database = MovieDatabase.getInstance(getApplication());
        movies = database.movieDao().getAllMovies();
        favouriteMovies = database.movieDao().getAllFavouriteMovies();
        errors = new MutableLiveData<>();
    }

    public LiveData<Throwable> getErrors() {
        return errors;
    }

    public void clearErrors() {
        errors.setValue(null);
    }

    public void loadData(String lang, String sort, String page) {
        ApiFactory apiFactory = ApiFactory.getInstance();
        ApiService apiService = apiFactory.getApiService();
        compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();

        Disposable disposable = apiService.getMovieResponse("32f91e104228c0c9ff3630899838e82e",
                        lang,
                        sort,
                        "1000",
                        page)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Consumer<MovieResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(MovieResponse movieResponse) throws Exception {
                        deleteAllMovies();
                        insertMovie(movieResponse.getMovies());

                    }
                }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                        errors.setValue(throwable);
                    }
                });
        compositeDisposable.add(disposable);
    }
    public void loadDataImage(String lang, String sort, String page) {
        ApiFactory apiFactory = ApiFactory.getInstance();
        ApiService apiService = apiFactory.getApiService();
        compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();

        Disposable disposable = apiService.getMovieResponse(
                        "32f91e104228c0c9ff3630899838e82e",
                        lang,
                        sort,
                        "1000",
                        page)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Consumer<MovieResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(MovieResponse movieResponse) throws Exception {

                        insertMovie(movieResponse.getMovies());
                    }
                }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                        errors.setValue(throwable);
                    }
                });
        compositeDisposable.add(disposable);
    }
    public Movie getMovieById(int id) {
        try {
            return new GetMovieTask().execute(id).get();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public FavouriteMovie getFavouriteMovieById(int id) {
        try {
            return new GetFavouriteMovieTask().execute(id).get();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public LiveData<List<FavouriteMovie>> getFavouriteMovies() {
        return favouriteMovies;
    }

    public void deleteAllMovies() {
        new DeleteMoviesTask().execute();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void insertMovie(List<Movie> movie) {
        new InsertTask().execute(movie);
    }

    public void deleteMovie(Movie movie) {
        new DeleteTask().execute(movie);
    }

    public LiveData<List<Movie>> getMovies() {
        return movies;
    }

    public void insertFavouriteMovie(FavouriteMovie movie) {
        new InsertFavouriteTask().execute(movie);
    }

    public void deleteFavouriteMovie(FavouriteMovie movie) {
        new DeleteFavouriteTask().execute(movie);
    }


    private static class DeleteFavouriteTask extends AsyncTask<FavouriteMovie, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(FavouriteMovie... movies) {
            if (movies != null && movies.length > 0) {
                database.movieDao().deleteFavouriteMovie(movies[0]);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static class InsertFavouriteTask extends AsyncTask<FavouriteMovie, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(FavouriteMovie... movies) {
            if (movies != null && movies.length > 0) {
                database.movieDao().insertFavouriteMovie(movies[0]);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static class DeleteTask extends AsyncTask<Movie, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Movie... movies) {
            if (movies != null && movies.length > 0) {
                database.movieDao().deleteMovie(movies[0]);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static class InsertTask extends AsyncTask<List<Movie>, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(List<Movie>... movies) {
            if (movies != null && movies.length > 0) {
                database.movieDao().insertMovie(movies[0]);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static class DeleteMoviesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... integers) {
            database.movieDao().deleteAllMovies();
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static class GetMovieTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Movie> {
        @Override
        protected Movie doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
            if (integers != null && integers.length > 0) {
                return database.movieDao().getMovieById(integers[0]);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static class GetFavouriteMovieTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, FavouriteMovie> {
        @Override
        protected FavouriteMovie doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
            if (integers != null && integers.length > 0) {
                return database.movieDao().getFavouriteMovieById(integers[0]);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCleared() {
        compositeDisposable.dispose();
        super.onCleared();
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class MovieAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieAdapter.MovieViewHolder> {

    private List<Movie> movies;
    private OnPosterClickListener onPosterClickListener;
    private OnReachEndListener onReachEndListener;
    private onStartLoadingListener onStartLoadingListener;

    public MovieAdapter(){
        movies = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public interface OnPosterClickListener{
        void OnPosterClick(int position);
    }
    public interface OnReachEndListener{
        void onReachEnd();
    }
    public interface onStartLoadingListener{
        void onStartLoading();
    }

    public void setOnStartLoadingListener(onStartLoadingListener onStartLoadingListener) {
        this.onStartLoadingListener = onStartLoadingListener;
    }
    public void setOnPosterClickListener(OnPosterClickListener onPosterClickListener) {
        this.onPosterClickListener = onPosterClickListener;
    }


    public void setOnReachEndListener(OnReachEndListener onReachEndListener) {
        this.onReachEndListener = onReachEndListener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MovieViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.movie_item, parent, false);
        return new MovieViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MovieViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (movies.size() >= 20 && position > movies.size() - 4 && onReachEndListener != null){
            onReachEndListener.onReachEnd();
        }
        Movie movie = movies.get(position);
        Picasso.get().load(movie.getPosterPath()).into(holder.imageViewSmallPoster);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return movies.size();
    }

    class MovieViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private ImageView imageViewSmallPoster;

        public MovieViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageViewSmallPoster = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewSmallPoster);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if(onPosterClickListener != null){
                        onPosterClickListener.OnPosterClick(getAdapterPosition());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void clear(){
        this.movies.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public List<Movie> getMovies() {
        return movies;
    }

    public void addMovies(List<Movie> movies){
        this.movies.addAll(movies);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void setMovies(List<Movie> movies) {
        this.movies = movies;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```